# Meaning of crystal orientation

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

If I have a crystal, say (001)-oriented ABO3, what does the 001 imply, from an *experimental* perspective? I understand that the 001 is referring to a plane as described by Miller indices, but what is it about this plane that is relevant? Is it that this plane is the same plane as the *surface* of the sample?

Answer (score 2):

When someone says (hkl)-oriented anything, they almost always mean the surface normal of the sample is parallel to (hkl). So Si-(111) would mean silicon oriented so the surface normal is along the (111) direction.

If you have a layered material, then having a (001) orientation means the c-axis is perpendicular to the surface of the sample. This is an extremely common orientation for layered crystals for example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. In a surface science experiment, it would be the surface. In experiments on bulk properties, the surface could be irrelevant and rough, but one would measure some property along a cubic axis (or maybe paricularly along the c-axis), like velocity of sound or conductivity, etc.